# I am trying to sort WordPress search results by taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, search

I'm trying to sort the WP search results page to prioritize a certain taxonomy term to the very top of the results. The actual search results are fine but they need to be resorted in a different way that is not the traditional ASC or DESC type.

I've looked into the hook `pre_get_posts` but that only alters the query before it is ran. I would ideally like to modify the results after the query has been ran.

Is there not a way to alter the array after the results have been fetched? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well, you could get the array of posts that's returned by your query then sort stuff manually to get your term-tagged posts first then everything else afterwards. To provide you some actual coding suggestions you'll want to share your code though, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As it relates to before or after, imagine that there are 11 items and your search is set to only return 10 at a time. If you do it _before_, you can guarantee that your item is the first. If you do it _after_, it might not even appear if it was naturally the 11th result.